# Does Dart support interfacing with the native libraries?

Tags: dart, dart-native-extension

As the server-side part becomes more complex, developers will need to leverage the existing software. So, does Dart support interfacing with the native libraries (C libraries, in particular)?

Comment: You just completely changed your question. It was originally about "whether or not it is possible to interface", after I added my answer you change it to "it's possible to interface, is it worth learning"

Comment: Sorry, how do I get back the old one and add an EDIT?

Comment: I moved what I was planning to add as an EDIT, to a a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible, [here is the official guide.](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/)

> Dart programs running on the standalone Dart VM (command-line apps) can call C or C++ functions in a shared library, by means of native extensions. This article shows how to write and build such native extensions on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux.
>
> You can provide two types of native extensions: asynchronous or synchronous. An asynchronous extension runs a native function on a separate thread, scheduled by the Dart VM. A synchronous extension uses the Dart virtual machine library’s C API (the Dart Embedding API) directly and runs on the same thread as the Dart isolate. An asynchronous function is called by sending a message to a Dart port, receiving the response on a reply port.